# Does it make any sense to prove $0.999\ldots=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, real-numbers, philosophy, decimal-expansion

I have read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-0-999999999-1) which contains many proofs of $0.999\ldots=1$.

### Background

The main motivation of the question was philosophical and not mathematical. If you read the next section of the post then you will see that I have asked for a "meaning" of the symbol $0.999\ldots$ other than defining it to be $1$. Now here is a epistemological problem and this is mainly the problem from which the question arose. Suppose you know that $1$ is a real number. Now I give you a symbol, say $0.999\ldots$ which from now on I will denote as $x$. Now I ask you whether $x$ is a real number. To answer this, if you define $x=1$ then you are already attributing the properties of $1$ to $x$ among which one is it being a real number without proving whether to $x$ we can indeed attribute the properties of $1$.

A common response to this question has been to define the symbol $x$ as the limit of the sequence $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{9}{10^i}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and then prove that the limit of this sum is indeed $1$. But again the problem is that **you are defining the symbol $x$ to be a real number and hence are assuming a priori that the symbol $x$ denotes a real number**.

As per the discussion that has been conducted with Simply Beautiful Art let me state my position again in brief,

> Also let me say that I do not disallow $0.999…$ to be a real number. My impression that if you assume $0.999…$ to be a real number then there is no sense in proving that $0.999…$ is indeed equal to $1$ because either you define it to be $1$ or you prove the equality as a theorem. But if you are going to use the limit definition of $0.999…$ then what you are a priori assuming it to be a real number which is an assumption that I don't allow. **What can be allowed is that $0.999…$ is a number (but not necessarily a real number).**

### **Question**

My question is,

> Does it make any sense to prove this equality?

Can one give any "meaning" of the symbol $0.999\ldots$ other than **defining** it to be $1$?

Comment: Well...you can define $.999...=\sum \frac 9{10^i}$ and then prove that this sum converges to $1$.  I'd say that had non-trivial content, no?

Comment: @lulu: I don't understand what you mean by $\sum\frac{9}{10^i}$?

Comment: @user170039 Then you need to go back to basics then. You can write finite decimals with a sum, then take the limit to infinity to produce infinite decimals. The convergence of the sum shows you that the result equals 1. That's called, an analytic way to prove it.

Comment: The first answer to the question you link to, with more than 250 upvotes, is likely to be as good an answer as you could possible get here, asking again.

Comment: $.999\ldots$ is not *defined* to be equal to $1$; it already has a definition as soon as decimal notation is defined.  When we define decimal notation, we agree that $.a_1 a_2 a_2 \ldots \text{ means } a_1/10 + a_2/100 + a_3/1000 + \cdots$.  It turns out that $.999... = 1$, but that's only a consequence of the definition of decimal notation.

Comment: There is a point to proving it, but you have to get to calculus to know the reason - it is an example of a limit and limits are very important.

Comment: @EthanBolker: But they're not asking for the proof they're asking a different question -- why do we need this proof?

Comment: $0.999\ldots $ is expressable as a series whose sum is $1$, there is no need to define it as $1$.

Comment: You should realize that in analysis, $a = b \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0$, $|a - b | < \epsilon$.

Comment: @T.S.L: But here $a$ and $b$ are any two "constants".

Comment: Yes, this holds for all real numbers.

Comment: @T.S.L: So you are assuming that $0.999\ldots$ is a real number?

Comment: Otherwise, how can you talk about being equal?

Comment: I think that from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/800827) an answer of my question can be found.

Comment: Saying $0.999\ldots = 1$ has much the same philosophical content as saying  $0.333\ldots = \dfrac13$, though it conveys the added information that some real numbers have more than one decimal representation.

Comment: When you ask whether we "assume" $0.999\ldots$ is a real number, what exactly do you mean by the word "assume"?  Would you say that if I defined the word "smalky" to mean "greenish-blue", then I am _assuming_ that smalky is a color?

Comment: @EricWofsey before we even consider decimals, we prove there is a number system in which every bounded set of rational numbers has real number limit in the system.  We call the system the Real Numbers..  {.9, .99, .999, .9999, etc} is a bounded set of rational numbers so it has a real number limit.  For notation, we refer  that real number limit as .9999......  So we don't 'assume' .999..... is a real number.  We *know* it is as that is what .9999...... means.

Comment: @vonbrand: Have you noted that the question you linked is exactly the question I linked?

Comment: Does it make sense to prove anything, ever? x = 0.999..., 10x = 9.999..., 9x = 9, x = 1

Comment: @littleO the point is that when you write an infinite sum $a_1/10 + a_2/100 + a_3/1000 + \cdots$ the three dots at the end are ambiguous because apriori addition is only defined for finite sums (by induction).

Comment: You yourself say: **"The main motivation of the question was philosophical and not mathematical."**  Then you're on the wrong site.

Comment: @amWhy: "The main motivation of the question was philosophical and not mathematical." - true. But that alone doesn't definitely mean that this question isn't fit for this site. Does it?

Comment: @MikhailKatz $a_1/10 + a_2/100 + a_3/1000 + \cdots$ is another way of writing $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i/10^i$, which is defined to be $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^N a_i/10^i$.

Comment: @littleO, exactly.  The sum is defined in terms of the limit concept and the limit concept is by definition real-valued.  So this doesn't answer the OP's question does it?

Comment: @MikhailKatz In my original comment, I was making the same point that was already made by lulu.  (lulu and I commented around the same time, although lulu was first.)

Comment: @littleO, it is your original comment that I was responding to.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I don't completely understand your objection. To clarify, does the objection apply equally well to lulu's comment?  I am just saying, we don't define $.\bar{9}$ to be equal to $1$, as the OP suggested.  Rather, we define it to be $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 9/10^i$, and the fact that it turns out to be equal to $1$ is a theorem which has to be *proved*, not a definition.  This is responding directly to OP's question about whether or not we should *define* $.\bar{9}$ to be $1$, and whether or not it is necessary to prove that $.\bar{9} = 1$. Most likely I'm missing your point.

Comment: @littleO, most students first encounter this identity before they learn a formal theory of either the real numbers or the concept of limit. As you know they often have different intuitions about "zero, dot, followed by an infinite number of nines" than the one you outlined. The question is whether their intuitions are necessarily erroneous, or whether they can be justified mathematically, as well.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Hmm, my original comment was posted before OP made the edit adding the background section and "a common response to this question has been..."  I'm not sure I understand the edited question -- specifically, why is it a problem that we define $\bar{9}$ to be a real number?  We do in fact define it to be the real number $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 9/10^i$, and that seems fine.  I'm not sure I agree with your interpretation of the question; perhaps you are reading something into it.  In any case, probably your answer is more helpful to OP than my short comment.

Comment: @littleO: "why is it a problem that we define $\bar 9$ to be a real number?" Certainly there is no problem to us as mathematicians, and furthermore most of us are puzzled by the apparently massive student resistance to this idea. But education studies clearly indicate that a vast majority of them don't accept it even after sitting in a calculus course :-) So it is reasonable to as as the OP does whether we *must* assume that it is a real number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP asked whether one can assign any *meaning* to the symbol $0.999\ldots$ other than defining it to be $1$.  That question cannot be answered without analyzing what *informal* pre-mathematical meaning is assigned to $0.999\ldots$, *prior to* interpreting it in a formal mathematical sense. This of course can only be known to the OP himself but judging from the level of the OP's questions the OP seems to be a *student* and perhaps a freshman; see, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537940).

Now beginning students often informally describe this as "zero, dot, followed by infinitely many $9$s", or something similar. Such a description of course does not refer to any sophisticated number system such as the real numbers, since at this level the students will typically not have been exposed to such mathematical abstractions, involving as they do equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, Dedekind cuts, and the like.

It is also known that at this level, about $80\%$ of the students feel that such an object necessarily falls a little bit short of $1$. The question is whether such intuitions are necessarily erroneous, or whether they could find a mathematically rigorous interpretation in the context of a suitable number system.

An article by R. Ely [in this publication in a leading education journal](http://www.nctm.org/publications/article.aspx?id=26196) argues that such intuitions are not necessarily mathematically erroneous because they can find a rigorous implementation in the context of a hyperreal number system, where a number with an infinite tail of $9$s can fall infinitesimally short of $1$ as outlined in a comment by user @GBeau on this page, namely if $H$ is an infinite hypernatural then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^H \frac{ 9}{10} =0.999\ldots9$ where the digit $9$ occurs $H$ times.

This is of course a *terminating* infinite string of $9$s different from the one usually envisioned in real analysis, but it respects student intuitions and can be helpful in learning the calculus, as argued in Ely's fascinating study.

The existence of such an interpretation suggests that we indeed do *assume* that such a string represents a real number when we prove that it necessarily equals $1$.

**Note I.** If one thinks of the infinite string as being represented by the sequence $0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \ldots$ then one can obtain an alternative interpretation as follows. Instead of taking its *limit* (which is by definition real-valued), one can take what Terry Tao refers to as its [*ultralimit*](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/ultralimit-analysis), to obtain a number than falls infinitesimally short of $1$.

These issues are dealt with in more detail in [this recent publication](http://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00191).

The challenging philosophical issue here is the idea that there are *distinct* ways of formalizing infinity in mathematics, and the possibility of an attendant *ambiguity* of the symbol in question. These issues were dealt with in more detail in [this publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10649-010-9239-4) in a leading education journal.

**Note II.** A certain number of objections have been raised by a colleague who wishes to remain anonymous.  Given below are the objections together with my responses.

> (0) You have not provided a meaningful syntactic representation of $1/3$ in the hyperreals.

Well $\dfrac13$ is the unending decimal $0.333\ldots$ (indexed by the hypernaturals). If truncated at infinite hypernatural rank $H$ this would produce a hyperrational falling infinitesimally short of a third, similarly to the $0.999\ldots{}$ situation.

> (1) Nobody can legitimately disagree that hyperreals can be constructed via the ultraproduct of the reals $\bf{R}$ within $\sf{ZFC}$, which is the mainstream foundations for mathematics.

True, analysis with infinitesimals can be done over the hyperreals, as pointed out by Robinson in 1961. Alternatively, this can be done syntactically in the context of the ordinary real line, following Edward Nelson's approach. Nelson's approach, called *Internal Set Theory* $(\sf{IST})$, involves enriching the language of set theory by the introduction of a single-place predicate $\textbf{st}$, as well as three additional axiom schemas governing its interaction with the other set-theoretic axioms. Here $\textbf{st}(x)$ reads "$x$ is standard".

> (2) Philosophically nobody has provided non-circular ontological arguments justifying $\sf{ZFC}$ (especially with replacement and choice). No logician, whether on Math SE or on Math Overflow or whom I have met, have done anything close to it.

This is a much broader issue. It is possible that $\sf{ZFC}$ has serious flaws. Nonetheless it happens to be currently the standard against which much of modern mathematics is tested. This doesn't mean that we must accept it, but it does mean that such philosophical problems are no smaller for the reals than for the hyperreals (especially in view of Nelson's syntactic approach mentioned above).

> I accept various things such as consistency of $\sf{ZF}$ implying consistency of $\sf{ZFC}$, but consistency is quite irrelevant to soundness besides being necessary. Unless you're happy with just $\prod_1$-soundness.

If the sound alternative is predicativism as developed by Sol Feferman and others, then certainly $\sf{ZF}$ is no less problematic than $\sf{ZFC}$. Practically speaking, $\sf{ZF}$ is not enough for some rather standard applications. Consider the following example: it is consistent with $\sf{ZF}$ that there exists a strictly positive real function with vanishing Lebesgue integral; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00493

> (3) The construction of the hyperreals is via the ultraproduct of the reals R. If you can construct the hyperreals, then you also can construct $\bf{R}$ and prove the usual second-order real axioms for $\bf{R}$. It would be self-contradictory to say that the properties of $\bf{R}$ (including $0.999... = 1$ suitably interpreted) are not intuitive and then claim that the hyperreals are intuitive. After all, we define an infinitesimal in the hyperreals as a nonzero sequence of reals that converges to zero...

I wouldn't argue that the properties of the reals are not intuitive. Rather, what was explored in several articles in the recent literature is the possibility that there may be multiple approaches to interpreting the business with "a tail with an infinite number of $9$s", some of which may be helpful in harnessing student intuitions in a productive direction rather than merely declaring them to be erroneous.

Incidentally, your definition of a hyperreal infinitesimal is not quite correct.

An important distinction here is between procedures taught in a calculus class and set-theoretical justification (ontology of the entities involved) usually treated in an analysis course. This applies both to the reals and the hyperreals.

> (4) Let $\bf{R}^\ast$ be the hyperreals and $\varepsilon = 1 - 0.999\ldots$. You claim that $\varepsilon$ is nonzero in a suitable interpretation of $0.999\ldots$ Ignoring the fact that you cannot represent $1/3$ meaningfully in similar decimal form, I now present you another fact that you can't represent $\varepsilon/2$, not to say $\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Wait, what does the latter even mean in the hyperreals. Can your students figure that out? Are you sure hyperreals are so intuitive now?

I am not sure what you mean. Both $1/3$ and $\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ are well-defined in the hyperreals, simply by the transfer principle. As far as teaching the set-theoretic justification of the hyperreals in terms of the ultrapower, as I mentioned this belongs in a more advanced course, just like set-theoretic justification of the reals.

> In contrast, asymptotic expansion can happily deal with $\sqrt{x}$ for any asymptotic expression $x$ that is non-negative. No trouble at all. $x^{1+x}$ for positive $x$? No problem.

All of these are well-defined over the hyperreals by the transfer principle.

Comment: Since the question has been put on hold, I have tried to explain my motivation a bit more. Please let me know if you find anything doubtful in it. By the way, the article that you linked is a very nice article and I think it precisely goes into the issues that I wanted to point at in this question but probably couldn't with sufficient clarity. Thank you very much for sharing the link to this article.

Comment: @user170039, you're welcome.  There are additional articles you may find of interest [here](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html).

Comment: I tried to read some of your articles that you have submitted to arXiv. However, there are some papers for which the link for pdf is not working properly and I thought that I should inform you that so that you may take a look at them.

Comment: I tried the links to the arXiv.

Comment: @user170039 I just tested the links and they seem to be working fine. When did you try last?

Comment: Just some seconds before posting the next-to-last comment.

Comment: Do you have access to the main site https://arxiv.org/find/math/ ?

Comment: @Mikhail It might prove helpful to *fully* cite the mentioned articles so that readers have an immediate clue that they refer to scholarly publications (as opposed to web pages authored by cranks). Also it might prove helpful to establish this scholarly context at the *beginning* of the answer. This may help to discourage any further downvotes from users who have not invested proper effort to distinguish this fine answer from the many cranky answers that are often given for such FAQs.

Comment: I want to emphasize my +1 on this; it's great that this post emphasizes that it's discussing a *terminating* decimal with infinitely many $9$'s. So many expositions neglect to give any indication that they're talking about something *different* from a nonterminating decimal, which I think sabotages the education of people who haven't yet conceived just what limits (and similar) are.

Comment: That's fine as far as I am concerned.  I was just thinking that the original meta post was an error because it led to many hostile responses. @user170039

Comment: @user170039 Do you refer to [my comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26488/are-these-type-of-practices-from-high-rep-users-acceptable?noredirect=1#comment104719_26488) about the paper by Rota et al, about the real numbers as a wreath product?  If so, then you are welcome to duplicate that as you like (but it would be out of context lacking the prior discussion).

Comment: @BillDubuque: I was talking about the link of the paper *A sample of Rota's mathematics* that you mentioned in the same comment that you linked above. The link that you gave there is not working for me.

Comment: @user170039 It appears there is currently a network connectivity problem reaching math.ou.edu. The goo.gl link resolves to  http://www.math.ou.edu/~dmccullough/teaching/slides/rotamath.pdf and you can find a cached version at archive.org

Comment: @BillDubuque: Ok. I will look at it. Many thanks for mentioning the valuable references.

Comment: For me, this is the answer that hits the nail on the head, namely that whether or not such a number equals one depends on the axiomatic system in which we are working. Therefore the answer is YES. In a given axiomatic system in which both symbols define elements of a set, one can legitimately ask for a proof that the elements they define are equal, when this is the case.

Comment: It is completely false that "philosophical problems are no smaller for the reals than for the hyperreals". Z is obviously enough to construct the reals, while **not** enough to construct the hyperreals. The transfer principle allows transferring first-order definable functions, but if your students don't know that then it's in my opinion wrong to claim that "it respects student intuitions and can be helpful in learning the calculus". Respecting **unsound** intuitions makes no sense, so you've to first justify that intuitions are sound before 'respecting them' is desirable.

Comment: The intuition of a terminating string with an infinite number of 9s is a sound one. Relative to an enriched language including the single-place predicate, one is working in the reals themselves and finding infinitesimals there. @user21820

Comment: I repeat myself; it's incorrect to claim that the philosophical problems in constructing the reals are no smaller than for the hyperreals. It seems you evaded that point. Secondly, significant impredicative use of the axiom of comprehension is necessary in constructing the hyperreals. The reals can be constructed in very weak foundations, as I think you very well know. Just like you don't consider natural numbers to be as philosophically problematic as ZFC just because modern mathematics has 'reduced' them to a construction within ZFC.

Comment: You insist on viewing analysis with infinitesimals through the lens of "hyperreals extending the reals" but if your concern is philosophy of the foundations then you may want to consider seriously Nelson's viewpoint where infinitesimals are found within the real number system itself. Infinitesimals were part of the natural language of analysis until Cantor, Dedekind, and Weierstrass sought (not completely successfully) to eliminate them since they were unable to formalize them. Today we have such a formalisation via the one-place predicate (I thought you liked predicates :-)  From this point..

Comment: .., of view analysis with infinitesimals is no more problematic than analysis over the reals, *because it IS analysis over the reals*. @user21820

Comment: I can now see why you didn't understand my point. Let me be clearer. You think that mere formalization is sufficient. I don't. Just because there are formalizations of NSA that can **natively** handle them (rather than ZFC indirectly handling them) does not mean that those formalizations are meaningful. One is free to create any formal system to capture **the concept** of any notion/structure, but it does not imply that the notion is meaningful and has an instantiation. I don't think you can show a model of that formalization of NSA without philosophically unjustifiable assumptions.

Comment: @user21820, since you seem to think that both ZF and ZFC are based on philosophically unjustifiable assumptions, it will be hard to convince you that IST is any better.  I think I do understand your point but the historical component is also important.  Infinitesimals were native soil to analysis but they were excised from foundational systems like ZFC because the rigorizers were unable to formalize them, and the only reason nowadays we have to work hard to put them back in is because they were unjustifiably taken out in the first place. You have made several references to issues in reverse...

Comment: ... mathematics and therefore I would like again to refer you to the work of Sam Sanders who develops substantial fragments of analysis in weak systems (of the kind of seem to favor) incorporating infinitesimals.  See [here](http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=hX_dTCMAAAAJ&hl=en).

Comment: @user21820 What "philosophically unjustifiable assumptions" are there in the foundations of NSA?

Comment: @DanielMoskovich, in my opinion, none. I think NSA is philosophically as justified as the rest of mathematics. You might want to ping user21820 if the question is addressed to him.

Comment: What do you mean by "meaningful" here @user21820? (I thought that for a concept to be meaningful, having an instantiation of it was both necessary and sufficient but since you write, "...but it does not imply that the notion is meaningful **and** has an instantiation." - I presume that you use the terms in different sense. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: I will say that your comment that "it will be hard to convince you that IST is any better" is correct, and I think you now do understand why. In my view history is irrelevant to **philosophical** justification. Do not forget that for many centuries the **dominant** worldview placed Earth at the centre of the universe. That worldview can **certainly** be formalized, but is **still** meaningless in any attempt to **sincerely** describe the universe, at least based on current science. You claim **incorrectly** that infinitesimals were unjustifiably taken out since **you have not justified them**.

Comment: @user21820, you have mentioned the idea of "philosophical justification" many times but it still seems vague to me.  You have also spoke about weaker logical systems that you find more sound than the usual ZF/ZFC fare.  If this is what you mean, then my response is that in the context of those weaker systems, work with infinitesimals can be successfully justified.  In addition to Sam Sanders I can mention the work by Jeremy Avigad, in a *very weak* system (I believe PRA).  If you are willing to bet your money on ZF, then note that Skolem developed is nonstandard models of arithmetic in ZF...

Comment: Taking the fraction field of those, one gets a basic system where basic analysis with infinitesimals can be practiced.

Comment: (Don't let get started on belief systems that have lasted for millennia.) Also, you keep mentioning reverse mathematics, but I believe you still fail to understand why those points are irrelevant. The reason is that without **prior** philosophical acceptance of infinitesimals or some formal system capable of constructing them, one cannot claim that various versions of NSA in weak systems are **meaningful**, because you can only 'observe' their meaning from formal systems such as ZFC that you **have not** yet justified to be meaningful. As for what I mean by "meaningful", ...

Comment: A sufficient notion for my purposes is that it has an interpretation in the real world, that many logicians would agree with. Note that many logicians would agree that PA is (at least approximately) meaningful.

Comment: @user170039: If a notion is meaningful but has no instantiation (such as "Russell's barber"), then it is meaningless to assume existence of an instantiation. This is why I keep saying nobody has shown that ZFC is meaningful in the sense that proponents **need**, namely that ZFC has a model... As a purely formal system, of course ZFC is meaningful and I too know how to describe the syntactic and deductive rules... So is chess.

Comment: @user21820, you write that "without prior philosophical acceptance of infinitesimals or some formal system capable of constructing them, one cannot claim that various versions of NSA in weak systems are meaningful". But as I mentioned, Skolem constructed nonstandard models in ZF which is a system weaker than what most of modern mathematics is based upon. This does respond to your concern to a certain extent.  Furthermore, Sanders and, earler, Avigad did this in even weaker logical systems, a point you don't seem willing to acknowledge.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Your last sentence is **false** again. This discussion is ridiculous because you keep assuming I don't know what I'm talking about. After I address your last comment, if you don't want to actually think carefully about what I say, I won't be bothered to reply. ZF does prove existence of non-standard models of the first-order theory of R (the reals). So what? ZF also proves the same for Th(N). It's stupid to expect anyone to consider PA+¬Con(PA) physically meaningful except as a purely syntactic game. You must philosophically distinguish reality from imagination. [continued]

Comment: [cont] As for the point that you think I didn't acknowledge, you seem to be not reading my comment carefully before responding I said already in my comment to @user170039 that you can treat formal systems as symbol-pushing games, and in **that sense** they are meaningful, but they do not necessarily have any **real-world** interpretation. PA has one (at least at small scales). PA+¬Con(PA) does not (even at small scales). ZF does not seem to. Nor does NSA. There is no physical evidence that infinitesimals exist in any reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @user21820: "There is no physical evidence that infinitesimals exist in any reasonable interpretation." - the same statement can be said about the natural numbers (or for $\sf{PA}$). If you don't agree then you need to explain why you think so. Thus in my opinion the problem of existence (in your sense) is the same for all the formal systems and not greater for infinitisemals only.

Comment: Also regarding your comment that "many logicians would agree that $\sf{PA}$ is (at least approximately) meaningful" I would like to know examples of logicians who is allegedly **not** a realist but still finds $\sf{PA}$ to be (at least approximately) meaningful.

Comment: @user170039: If you believe that **logic itself** is meaningful, you **have to** believe the basic properties of finite strings. That gives essentially a **real-world** model of PA−. From that model of PA− you get a model of PA from the standard numerals. I have definitely told you this numerous times before; do read and understand what I tell you to before judging my statements without a background in logic.

Comment: @user170039: By my above comment every logician who believes their work is meaningful **must** also believe that PA is (at least at small scales) meaningful. So pick any logician who believes that ZFC has nothing to do with the real world. A separate and perhaps more compelling argument is that you use 2048-bit RSA decryption every time you visit Math SE. If you seriously doubt that PA (or at least the fragment needed to prove that RSA decryption works) has real-world meaning, then you have a serious inability to explain why you can use Math SE.

Comment: @DanielMoskovich: It is obvious that basic arithmetic has real-world meaning when you need to count apples or use real-world money. It is nowhere as obvious that anything at all in the universe corresponds to something like the first uncountable ordinal. You can see all my above comments for many other relevant points, but to avoid cluttering up the thread under Mikhail's answer, if you want to further discuss my views let's continue [in the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic).

Comment: @user21820, you wrote: "There is no physical evidence that infinitesimals exist in any reasonable interpretation." It is difficult to agree with this since you don't specify what you mean by *infinitesimals* exactly. There are non-Archimedean systems that are as easy to construct as $\mathbb R$ which you acknowledge can be meaningfully constructed.  For example, instead of using an ultrafilter one can use the Frechet filter and much work has been done exploring how much analysis can be done in this framework (a lot).

Comment: @user21820, you wrote: "If you believe that logic itself is meaningful, you have to believe the basic properties of finite strings. That gives essentially a real-world model of PA−." Your underlying assumption is that the notion of *finite* has a well-defined "real-world" meaning. Such an assumption has been challenged by a number of experts in the field, including Joel David Hamkins; see a number of related posts, e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654241/72694).

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Let's continue this discussion in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65129/philosophy-of-mathematics).

Comment: @user21820, logical theories are in a *meta*language only using the [naive integers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/231111/28128). Therefore this does not involve a commitment to a really or physically existing collection $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @user21820: If we have some prior notion of "the reals", then we *don't* know that Z is enough to construct them. Z constructs an object it calls $\mathbb{R}$ that we can identify in any model of Z, but there is no reason whatsoever that that object should be "the reals". It may even be possible that there isn't *any* model of Z whose $\mathbb{R}$ is "the reals".

Comment: @user21820: Of course "the first uncountable ordinal" doesn't correspond to a thing. Even $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't correspond to a *thing* in the universe. Only a minuscule fraction of members in a universe of sets are meant to correspond to actual *things* when interpreted as describing reality. Others are higher-order concepts (e.g. the "set of events in the universe") or relating to abstract reasoning (e.g. $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @Hurkyl: If you read my other comments, I think it is quite clear that when I said "anything" I meant "any real-world entity or concept". For example, the collection of Hurkyl's posts on Math SE is a real-world concept, even though it does not literally exist as a single physical entity. Same with the interpretation of addition of PA as a real-world procedure for addition of some suitable representation of naturals such as finite binary strings. If you have a real-world interpretation of ZF in this sense, describe it.

Comment: @user21820, the bit about "finite binary strings", combined with vilification of the traditional set-theoretic foundations, has already been argued *ad nauseam* by Errett Bishop, but won him few disciples; see [this](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html#11a). But this has strictly nothing to do either with this *question* or with this *answer*.

Answer (score 23):

We have to agree about what the symbols

$$
0.99999\dots
$$

are supposed to mean. The symbols capture an intuitive idea, but it doesn't have meaning unless we agree on what that meaning is. When you write these symbols down, everyone will agree that what you mean is the following:

$$
.9 + .09 + .009 + \dots = \frac{9}{10} + \frac{9}{100} + \frac{9}{1000} + \dots = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^i}
$$

There is no proof of that -- it is an agreement.

If you wrote this, perhaps similar-looking, string of symbols down

$$
\begin{aligned}
0.00000\dots1\\
\end{aligned}
$$

then there is no agreement on what you mean. You would seem to be talking about a real number which is smaller than all other real numbers -- an object that doesn't exist.

So what string of symbols means what, rigorously, is a matter of agreement. Usually we elide that fact when it seems intuitive what we mean, but we do not all share the same intuition (or the same knowledge of how to express that intuition), so we must drag it out on occasions like now.

Anyway, the content of a proof of $0.9999\dots = 1$ is **not** that we must agree to *define* $0.9999\dots$ as $1$. The content is to define $0.9999\dots$ as the sum above, then by *deduction* show this sum is equal to $1$.

Comment: So, we **are** assuming beforehand that $0.999\ldots$ is a real number, right?

Comment: @user170039: Yep. We're assuming it to mean $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{9}{10^i}$, an infinite sum, which is a real number because it converges.

Comment: We aren't assuming.  Before we even think about this we define what real numbers are and prove the real number system exists (very analytical and obscure).  By the proof and construction of what real numbers are, it comes out that all bounded sets of rational numbers have limits and these limits are always real numbers.  {.9, .99,.999, etc.} is one of these bounded sets or rational numbers and $.999\overline9$ is the notation of its limit. And therefore we *know* $.999\overline9$ is a real number because all limits are real numbers and all bounded sets have limits.

Comment: @EliRose I believe you meant to start your sum at $i=1$.

Comment: @fleablood, if you assume that the string is the limit then the answer follows because limits are defined to be real-valued; therefore you *are* assuming that the string represents a real number.  Not that there is anything wrong with that, but it *is* an assumption.

Comment: @user72694 that's a very broad and beyond the norm use of the word "assume".  I no more assume the string to be the limit than I assume this string of letters to be an english sentence. Or than I assume the symbol 4 to be a number. A string of a period followed by a series of digits is a defined as notation for a type of sum.  Yes we assume that is what those squiggles on a screen mean.  But we do *not* assume an infinite sum of that sort is the limit of rationals.  We know it is so. (it's nothing special about these sums.  All real number are limits or rationals.)

Comment: @user72694: The fact that there exist other definitions of "limit" in different contexts doesn't mean that choosing one definition is making an "assumption", unless you have a very strange definition of "assumption".

Comment: @user72694: I think the question itself is fine and have voted to reopen it.  This sidebar about whether making a definition involves "assuming" that the definition is true is a pointless semantic distraction.  As far as I can tell, we are just arguing about what the word "assume" means and not disagreeing about any actual substance.  This would be harmless, except that OP seems to be insisting that the fact that we are making an "assumption" (by their definition) means the entire enterprise is somehow flawed.

Comment: @user72694: I agree -- this question was marked as duplicate, but the question it's putatively a duplicate of is about proving that $0.999\dots = 1$, not about whether it makes sense to do so. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 15):

Many of the OP's questions in the comments (both to his own question and to Eli Rose's answer) keep circling back to the question "*Are you assuming that $0.999\dots$ is a real number*"?

The answer is no, we are not assuming it -- it can be *proven*.  More generally, the following theorem can be proven:

> Let $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ be any sequence of numbers where each $a_i$ is chosen from the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$.  Then the sequence
>   $$0.a_1, \space 0.a_1a_2, \space 0.a_1a_2a_3,\dots$$
>   converges to a unique real number.

Again I want to stress that the theorem above is not *assumed*; it can be *proven*.

The notation $0.999\dots$ denotes the unique real number that is the limit of the sequence $$0.9, \space 0.99, \space 0.999, \space 0.9999\dots$$  This is just an individual instance of the general case considered in the theorem.  We know that such a limit exists by the theorem , so there is no need to *assume* that $0.999\dots$ is a real number.

Once we know that $0.999\dots$ is a real number, and that in particular it is the limit of the sequence above, we can observe that this particular sequence converges to $1$.  Since the theorem says that the limit of the sequence is unique, that proves that $0.999\dots \space = 1$.

Comment: If I understand correctly then what you are saying is what **lulu** said earlier. *Define* $0.999\ldots=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{9}{10^i}$ and then *prove* that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{9}{10^i}=1$. Then by the uniqueness of the limit of a sequence $1=0.999\ldots$. But then again the question is: how can you write the equality in $0.999\ldots=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{9}{10^i}$ if you don't *assume* that it is a real number?...

Comment: By first proving a general theorem and *then* introducing a notational convention.

Comment: I don't understand, how this answers my question asked in the last comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: (1) Prove the theorem I highlighted in my box. We now know that there is a real number that represents the limit of a certain sequence.

Comment: (2) Introduce the notational convention that an "infinite decimal" represents the limit of that sequence.

Comment: (3) Now prove that the limit of the particular sequence under consideration is 1.

Comment: At no point in this process is anything being assumed to exist.

Comment: It *is* assumed in (2) that we can "[i]ntroduce the notational convention that an "infinite decimal" represents the limit of that sequence" and when that is assumed, you are assuming that that "notational convention" which represents an "infinite decimal" is indeed a real number (otherwise, you can't write $=$, assuming the usual meaning of $=$).

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/800827).

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know why you're having trouble understanding this. *First* we prove that a certain number exists.  *Then* we introduce a notational shorthand for referring to that number, which we have already proven exists. To do that we do *not* need to use the $=$ sign; we just say "Let the limit of the sequence be denoted with the following symbol."

Comment: Michael, if you assume as in (2) that the sequence represents the *limit* then you are certainly assuming what you are trying to prove, since limits are by definition real-valued! There is a vicious circle in your argument. To clarify the point further, note that if instead of *limit* you use what Terry Tao calls *ultralimit*, then the infinite string of 9s will indeed give you a number infinitely close to but smaller than $1$. Perhaps this is what @user170039 is trying to say.

Comment: @mweiss, as per above.

Comment: @user170039: You are using the word "assume" in a rather bizarre way.  When you make a definition, you aren't assuming that that definition is correct; you are simply giving meaning to a symbol which previously had no meaning.  Until you declare that $0.999\dots$ refers to the the value of a certain limit, it is a meaningless string of symbols.  (It is fair to ask why you would choose to define that string of symbols to refer to a real number rather than something else, but that is a different question.)

Comment: @user170039 your question of assumptions is astute. and important.  However what you are /unaware of (and how can you be aware of it; it's an advanced theoretical result that is not taught outside of real analysis classes) is that the real number system was analyzed and determined to be such that every real number is a bounded limit of a sequence of rationals and that every bounded sequence or rationals has a limit that is real.  So in that light we define .999... as the limit and we have a previous known result that all such limits are real.

Comment: I think that most who haven't had an analysis course don't realize is that *before* we prove all 0.a1a2a3.... have real limits is that what real numbers *are* is limits

Comment: @EricWofsey, *limits* by definition are real-valued, and therefore you *are* making an assumption.  Needless to say it is a fine assumption, but it is one nonetheless.

Comment: @user72694 No, limits are not by definition real-valued.  Real values by definition are limits.  That a consistent number system of limits works and is what our number system is is  concrete and proven result of analysis.  You seem to have it backwards that we define these sequences first, declare them  to have limits and declare limits to be real.  It's the opposite.  We proved our numbers are all limits and discovered that numbers and sequences to bounded limits are one and the same.  It's only after that that we concluded infinite decimals are well-defined.  *NO* assumptions.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate either.  But I guess part of what is misleading is that "proving" that .999... = 1 is trivial and beside the point.  If .999.... means and is equal to anything it's trivial to show that that thing must be 1.  But the subtle thing is "Are we assuming that .999... is a real number".  I say we are not.  I say we first define/discover what a real number is. I want to avoid the "is mathematics invented/discovered debate" but real numbers do "exist" and are "defined" in the same way that rationals are and addition and multiplication a calculus is.... to be continued...

Comment: ... con't... (and I think addition, multiplication and calculus are *not* assumptions)... And in that definition/discovery/construction of real numbers (which I do *not* think is an assumption), from *there* we find that decimal expressions, even infinite decimal expressions, are indeed meaningful well-defined ideas that are all real numbers.  So then everything tumbles out: .999.... is well-defined and has a real value, it's real value is 1, 1 = .9999.....  But it all hinges on knowing what a real number *is*.  And the thing is, we *never* teach anyone what it is.

Comment: @fleablood, you wrote above that "real values by definition are limits" but I am mostly familiar with 4 constructions of the reals: (1) equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences; (2) Dedekind cuts; (3) via an equivalence relation on infinite strings, as explained in my *answer*; (4) via almost homomorphisms of the integers. Which construction do you have in mind here?

Comment: @EricWofsey: "Until you declare that $0.999…$ refers to the the value of a certain limit, it is a meaningless string of symbols." But when we declare that "$0.999…$ refers to the the value of a certain limit" (in these case, it seems to me the limit of a real sequence), we **are** assuming that $0.999…$ is a real number because the limit of a real sequence by definition is a real number. Isn't it?

Comment: No. First you prove that a certain limit exists, without making reference to the string $0.999....$ at all.  Then you declare that the sting refers to that limit, which has been already proven to exist.  I really feel like you didn't read my answer.

Comment: "Then you declare that the sting refers to that limit, which has been already proven to exist" and is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this question is more than 1.5 years old, and I presume you now know how the structure of the real numbers is constructed in mathematics and proven to satisfy the second-order completeness axiom, which can then be used to **define** $0.99\overline9$ and **prove** that it is equal to $1$. But in the interest of future readers, here is a similar looking question that may give insight into why this question stems from a conceptual misunderstanding:

> I have seen many proofs of $1+2+\cdots+n = \frac12 n(n+1)$ for natural $n$. Now suppose you know that $\frac12 n(n+1)$ is an integer. Now I give you an expression, say $1+2+\cdots+n$ which from now on I will denote as $x$. Now I ask you whether $x$ is an integer. To answer this, if you define $x = \frac12 n(n+1)$ then you are already attributing the properties of $\frac12 n(n+1)$ to $x$ among which one is it being an integer without proving whether to $x$ we can indeed attribute the properties of $\frac12 n(n+1)$.
>
> A natural response to this question is to define the expression $x$ as the sum of all the integers from $1$ to $n$, and then prove that this sum is indeed $\frac12 n(n+1)$. But again the problem is that you are defining the expression $x$ to be an integer and hence are assuming a priori that the expression $x$ denotes an integer.
>
> My impression that if you assume $1+2+\cdots+n$ to be an integer then there is no sense in proving that $1+2+\cdots+n$ is indeed equal to $\frac12 n(n+1)$ because either you define it to be $\frac12 n(n+1)$ or you prove the equality as a theorem. But if you use the summation definition of $1+2+\cdots+n$ then you are a priori assuming it to be an integer, an assumption that I don't allow. What can be allowed is that $1+2+\cdots+n$ is a number (but not necessarily an integer).
>
> My question is, does it make any sense to prove this equality? Can one give any "meaning" of the expression $1+2+\cdots+n$ other than defining it to be $\frac12 n(n+1)$?

I hope it is clear where this goes wrong:

- We **indeed** define the expression "$1+2+\cdots+n$" to have a certain value, in a certain way (using recursion). For this we need to work in a foundational system that can **construct** the needed recursion and then prove the existence of a **function** that satisfies the recursion, and then **define** the value of "$1+2+\cdots+n$" according to that function. It then is **non-trivial** to prove that this value is $\frac12 n(n+1)$.
- We **never** assume a priori that the expression "$1+2+\cdots+n$" denotes an integer. Defining "$1+2+\cdots+n$" by the summation does **not** assume that the sum is an integer. As in the first point, the "summation" here is the recursive construction, which we can easily **prove** yields a function from naturals **to integers**, and so in particular "$1+2+\cdots+n$" has integer value.
- It does not make sense to say "What can be allowed is that $1+2+\cdots+n$ is a number (but not necessarily an integer).". Why? Because even if you have defined what "number" means, how can you 'allow' some arbitrary expression to be a number? As in the first point, we **define** the value of the expression, and whether or not it is an integer is **not up to us**.

Similarly:

- We **can define** "$0.99\overline9$" to denote the **unique** real $x$ that is a lowest upper bound for the set $\{0,0.9,0.99,\cdots\}$. You can ask how we define "$\{0,0.9,0.99,\cdots\}$". Exactly the same kind of recursion as in the previous analogy. You can further ask how we define things like "0.99". Again, by some suitable recursion. After all, we **cannot define** decimal notation without recursion. This definition of "$0.99\overline9$" is **valid**, because after the standard construction of the structure of the reals, we can **prove** the second-order completeness axiom, which gives us the **theorem** that there is indeed a **unique** such $x$...
- One might ask whether it is valid to assign values to expressions based on objects that we have proven to exist. We can do so with no qualms if we can **uniquely** identify each object that we wish to assign to each expression. In logic this is equivalent to asking whether we can extend a first-order theory by a function-symbol (for the value assignment function) if we can prove that there is a $2$-parameter property $P$ such that for every input $i$ from the desired domain there is a unique object $j$ such that $P(i,j)$ is true. This is not only possible (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864310/21820) for the technical details), but also yields a conservative extension, so we are not making any more philosophical commitment than we already did in using the original system.
- If you think that the above definition of "$0.99\overline9$" is not **intuitive**, here is another one. Define "$0.99\overline9$" as the unique real $x$ that lies in all the intervals $[0,1],[0.9,1.0],[0.99,1.00],\cdots$. After all, any **layman** that has read about $π$ 'knows' that "$3.14...$" denotes something that lies between $3.14$ and $3.15$ inclusive, and that having more digits will **narrow** down that interval. It turns out that this 'more intuitive' definition is 'more demanding' than the earlier one, since ignoring the upper endpoints of the sequence of intervals gives the earlier one.

If anyone objects that my analogy is inaccurate because "everyone knows what $1+2+\cdots+n$ means", it just shows that they themselves do not know how to precisely define it. **Every** rigorous definition of "$1+2+\cdots+n$" **must** invoke recursion. **Every** rigorous definition of "$0.99\overline9$" that captures the notion of the infinite decimal expansion must likewise invoke recursion.

The second definition of "$0.99\overline9$" using narrowing intervals has the **pedagogical** advantage that it is far easier to understand each decimal as an approximation scheme for reals. A decimal could be understood as a oracle that spits out one digit at a time, each of which puts a more precise bound on the 'real' value. Furthermore, it is natural to consider computable decimals, namely those digit oracles that are programs. One can then see that there is a crucial **distinction** between decimals and the reals they represent; clearly "$0.99\overline9$" and "$1.00\overline0$" are represented by **different** digit oracles, and whether they approximate the same 'real' value is a totally separate question.

By the way, to explicitly address the notion that the idea that $0.99\overline9 < 1$ can be 'correct' with a different definition of "$0.99\overline9$", note that **if** it were so, then one would **naturally** expect to have $0.33\overline3 = 0.99\overline9 \div 3 < 1 \div 3 = \frac13$ since there is exact division of each digit. But **then** $\frac13$ would not have a decimal representation. How weird... It may be possible to 'fix' this somehow, but any 'fix' is going to be **weirder and less intuitive** than $0.99\overline9 = 1$. Try it!

Finally, mathematicians do **not** define "$0.99\overline9$" to be $1$, because it is as meaningless as defining it to be $2$. However, **if** you choose to define "$0.99\overline9$" as $1$ **then** it becomes **non-trivial** that there is no upper bound for $\{0,0.9,0.99,\cdots\}$ that is smaller than $0.99\overline9$. So whatever way you pick, the fact remains that there is a non-trivial theorem that corresponds to $\sum_{k=1}^n 9·10^{-k} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Concerning rigorous recursion, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1893865/21820).

Comment: You write "By the way, to explicitly address the notion that the idea that $0.99\overline9 < 1$ can be 'correct' with a different definition of "$0.99\overline9$", etc." This is quite correct: one  cannot define the unending decimal $0.99\overline9$ in any other way, whether in the reals or the hyperreals.  However, it seems to me that you are changing the subject--or moving the goalpost--here. The OP is clearly not referring to the unending decimal $0.99\overline9$ which is certainly uniquely defined and equals $1$, but rather to a broader discussion of what kind of meaning to be assigned...

Comment: ... to "a tail of an infinite number of 9s".  Given that there is a whole literature devoted to this subject and its usefulness in harnessing students' intuitions in a constructive direction, your stomping the ground a little harder does little to advance the debate. @user170039

Comment: @MikhailKatz: You said in your own answer "Instead of taking its limit (which is by definition real-valued), one can take what Terry Tao refers to as its ultralimit, to obtain a number than falls infinitesimally short of 1.", which explicitly states that there is an interpretation of "0.999..." that makes "0.999... < 1" true. I did not move any goalpost; I explicitly mention that to show that any such alternative interpretation is **not intuitive**. Nowhere did I say in my answer that the asker believed that, so what you thought (seems to be moving goalpost) is simply false.

Comment: What's involved here is the distiction between *procedure* on the one hand and (set-theoretic) *ontology*, on the other, as I mentioned in the extended version of my *answer*. I can elaborate if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $0.99999\dots$ means $\dfrac 9 {10} + \dfrac 9 {100} + \dfrac 9 {1000} + \dots = \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \dfrac 9 {10^n}$.

Now, in your opinion, does it make sense to "define" this series to be $1$? Of course not, because otherwise we may "define" anything to be anything. For instance, we may "define" $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \dfrac 1 n$ to be $3$; does this look correct to you?

Does it make sense to show that the above series converge and that its limit is $1$? Yes, of course, it"s a simple exercise in real analysis. Therefore, it does make sense to prove that $0.99999\dots = 1$.

Comment: Surely "we may "define" $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \dfrac 1 n$ to be $3$". But I don't understand what you wanted to mean when you said "does this look correct to you?" What do you mean by looking "correct" here?

Comment: @user170039: No, of course you can't "define" it, because $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty x_n$ is already *defined* as $\lim \limits _{N \to \infty} \sum \limits _{n=1} ^N x_n$. Given that $\lim \limits _{N \to \infty} \sum \limits _{n=1} \frac 1 n = \infty$, defining $\lim \limits _{N \to \infty} \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \frac 1 n$ to be $3$ will lead to the contradiction $3 = \infty$. To conclude: given that $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \dfrac 9 {10^n}$ already has a meaning as a convergent series, it *is* equal to $1$, not *defineable* to be $1$!

Comment: I can "define" it. What you are saying is that whether my definition is "consistent" or not. But that has no (at least it seems so to me) relation to the "definition" itself.

Comment: Also, why "$0.999\ldots$ means $\dfrac{9}{10}+\dfrac{9}{10}+\dfrac{9}{10}+\ldots=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{9}{10^n}$"?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we assign a meaning to $0.999...$?

$1=0.999...$ may be written as

$$\begin{align}
1&=\frac{9}{10}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{10^k}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{10}\right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{10^k}\\
\end{align}
$$

This is case $r=\frac{1}{10}$ of the more general

$$1=(1-r)\sum_{k=0}^\infty {r}^k, |r|<1$$

The product $(1-p)p^k$ has probabilistic interpretations. For instance, in the context of [Nondeterministic finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), it is the probability of exiting a state that has self-transition probability $p$ after exactly $k$ self-transitions. Summing for all nonnegative integers represents the probability of exiting after any possible number of self-transitions. Therefore, the question about $.999...=1$ may be rewritten as

> What is the probability that a state with self-transition probability $p=\frac{1}{10}$ is exited?

Comment: Indeed, it might be an infinitesimal probability, as explored in a number of recent articles. Your approach answers the question in the negative only if you *assume* that there are no infinitesimals in the number system being used.

Comment: An infinitesimal probability that it is never exited, right?

Comment: Right. If your model of the process is that there is an infinite number (in the sense of Robinson's framework, for instance) of simultaneous tries then indeed there will be a positive infinitesimal probability that it does not exit.

Comment: I admit I should read those articles before, but just for intuition, let me ask: is that infinitesimal probability any similar to the probability of picking exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ when choosing randomly a real number in $(0,1)$ under uniform distribution? It is possible, not impossible as picking, say, $\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Jaume, very good question.  The answer is negative: it is *not* similar.  Rather, it is similar to picking a number in an infinitesimal interval centered on $\frac{1}{2}$. If you are intrigued by these ideas I would recommend Keisler's excellent textbook [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) as a first try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for info and educating me :)

Answer (score 0):

From epistemological point of view, there is no difference in that question and the question if some two objects are both elephants. If they share the same set of properties that defines an object being an elephant, they are. One elephant might have a leg missing or very short trunk, or broken tusk, and still be an elephant.

The same for $0.9999\cdots$ and $1$.

When you talk about $1$ you usually consider a unique element, known as *identity element*, that is required to exist within multiplication of real numbers, we will mark it as $e$. It satisfies $a \cdot e=a, a \neq 0$. That is what we are looking for. $e$ not $1$ or $0.999\cdots$. Why $e$? Because it gives as the set of properties to check if $1$ and $0.999\cdots$ are both elephant.

From that point of view,  $1$ or $0.999\cdots$ are two equivalent representations of $e$.

So there is *nothing* to prove. All proofs are actually quite artificial and actually make it more complicated, because any proof that $0.999\cdots=1$ already contains the axiom that they are equal. It must contain it. So it does not say anything new or moves us into a direction of some sort of clarification.

Sure, if you understand $0.999\cdots$ as a series, then you need to prove that its limit is $1$, but that is way advanced and no different than singing an English lullaby for no reason suddenly in Chinese.

To "prove" that $0.999\cdots$ and $1$ belong to the same class of equivalence, all you need is the defined set of properties of real numbers. This is always implied, since if we are not looking into reals, they do not have to be the same whatsoever. For example, lexicographically, obviously, they are not the same words and so on. It is the concept of real numbers that is making them equivalent words, words with the same meaning: potayto, potahto. It is an edible plant. And that is what I am concerned of, since I am hungry. The same, I need something that will represent an element that does nothing during the multiplication. And for that I can use either.

Answer (score -1):

We *don't* simply define $0.9999.... $ to be equal to 1.

We do a *lot* of background analysis first which involves *constructing* the real numbers out of the rational numbers.

In *very* short summary:

Consider this basic fact about rational numbers:  no matter how close together two rational numbers are we can find a rational number between them (which also means for any value greater than zero, no matter how small, you can find a smaller one between it and zero).

This is nice.  It means we can get as close as we like to any value using rational numbers.

Now consider this monkey wrench:  There are many values we *can't* express (for example: pi and the square root of 2).  [This is weird because we can get as close as we like to to these values by the statement above.]

And consider this *horrible* result:  Between any two rationals no matter how close we get, there is always one of the inexpressible holes between them!

So *how* can we think of these ... *ir*rational values...

Well, a lot of subtle analysis and picayune debating we notice that in the rational numbers we can have an infinite set of rationals, where all the rationals are within a range, but the set needn't have a biggest value.  For example: {all the rational numbers less than pi}; all these values are less than 3 1/3 so it's bounded, but there is no precise rational upper bound to this set.

(Another such set is all the numbers $.9, .99, .999, .9999$ etc.  It's infinite but each term is rational.  It has no biggest value.  And all values are less than 1.)

So the issue was can we come up with a bigger system of numbers than the rationals, where every set will have a precise upper bound? Mathematicians decided they could and it was called the Real numbers[1].

Now here is the definition of the real numbers and how the were created (it's *very* subtle):  Every real number is the least upper bound limit of a bounded set of rational numbers.  And every bounded set of rational numbers has a real number as an upper bound.

That's the *definition* of the real numbers.

So {.9, .99, .999, .9999,.....} is an bounded infinite set of rational numbers.  By definition it has a real number least upper bound limit.  We call that real number .999999999999......

Okay, we have defined .99999...... and we *DIDN'T* define it as 1.  So now we can prove that it does equal 1.

The general idea is that if .99999......= c < 1  then can find a *finite* number in {.9, .99, .999, .9999,.....}  that is bigger than c.  So we were wrong about c being an upper bound of {.9, .99, .999, .9999,.....}  So .9999....... $\ge$ 1.  But 1 is bigger than any of the {.9, .99, .999, .9999,.....}. So .99999.......  $\not >$ 1.  The only consistent option left is .99999.... = 1.

[1] Well, the didn't just wave their hands and declare it.  They had to prove constructing such a number system was possible.  The proof is ... abstract.  And tedious.  And abstract.

## ===== 2nd answer: Different approach and philosophy====

The OP has a point that we don't really "need" to prove .999.... = 1.  If .999... equals anything at all, showing that it must by 1 is trivially easy.  The idea of proving .999.... = 1 misses the point.  The point really is how do we know that .999.... equals anything at all.

The OP isn't entirely accurate in stating we defined .999... to be 1.  We defined .999.... to be something that can be shown to be 1.  (Slight difference but a difference with ramifications.)  Other comments claim we make an assumption via definitions that .999... is a limit of bounded sequence of rational numbers and another assumption via definition that limits of bounded sequence of rational numbers are real numbers.

These aren't entirely accurate either.  The definitions weren't assumptions.  They were analysis as to what the real numbers are and the discoveries came along the way.

Suppose we know nothing about the real numbers.  ... well,  not *nothing* but suppose we have no real sense of them.

With or without real numbers we do have to define $ 0.9999....$ as $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^n}$.  But we don't really know anything about it.  It's possible that it's unbounded and "blows up".  (Actually, we can show that can't happen but I don't want to get into that yet.)  It's possible that it adds up to an actual number.  It could be rational or it could be one of those numbers that can't be written as a rational like square root of two or pi.

But the natural concern is that it might simply never resolve into anything.

To me, the surprising and subtle thing about analyzing the real numbers is the realization that the very nature of the real numbers means that this "simply never resolving into anything" is impossible.  *Everything* in the reals that is bounded resolves to something, and every real is a resolution of something.  This *really* astounded me when I *finally* wrapped my head ahead.  I mean it *really* *really* surprised me!  (Yes, I'm that much a geek.)

Okay, so this leads to the fundamental question:  Real Numbers.  What the Heck are they?

We know that we can measure discrete units via integers, like $n$.  And we know we can chop these discrete units into $m$ pieces as $1/m$ and as $m$ can be arbitrarily large, these $1/m$ can be arbitrarily precise and this collection of ratios, so all the possible $n/m; m \ne 0$ form a system of arbitrarily precise measurements that span every possible range.  So these Rationals can measure anything to arbitrary precision.

That ought to be enough.

But it isn't.  Because we know there are always numbers like $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$ that can't be written as any Rational = $m/n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers.

So w have gone for a thousand years with a number system that we don't really understand and cant describe.  What are these "holes" and what do we know about them?

Enter the Dedekind cut.

An example:  Let's "cut" the rationals into two sets.  Set $A = ${all the rational numbers, $r$, such that $r^2 < 2$} and $B = ${all the rational numbers, $s$, such that $s^2 < 2$}.  Several things we note about these sets:

1) they are completely disjoint and neither are empty; 2) all the elements or 1 are smaller than all the elements of the other; 3) A does not have a largest element and B does not have a smallest element; and 4) They are arbitrarily close together.  (That is, for any number $e > 0$ no matter how small we can always find an $a \in A$ and a $b \in B$ so that $b - a < e$.  Always.)

Any "procedure" that can cut the Rational numbers into two sets with those 4 properties is called a "cut" and we can, for sake of vocabulary, refer to such cut as $\overline x$ and the two sets as $A\overline x$ and $B\overline x$.

And we can consider the collection of all such cuttings. One thing is about these cuts is that we don't necessarily need to know how to describe them for them to exist.

One such cut could be $\overline \omega$ such that $A\overline \omega = $ {all rationals less than some .99...9} and $B\overline \omega = $ {all rationals larger than all .99...9}.  [*That's not actually true and I pulled a fast one on you.  A brownie point to any one who can figure out my deception.*]

Now the astute reader might have noticed that although these cuts cut the rational in two, the two sets don't always contain all the rationals.  Ex: A = {all rationals < 27 1/2} and B = {all rationals > 27 1/2} is a cut.  But the rational number 27 1/2 is not in either A nor B.  This is okay.  The sets don't have to contain all the rationals.  But notice, 27 1/2 is the *only* rational that is not in either set.

We can say a cut like that one cuts the rationals "on" a rational number and others cut the rationals "between" rational numbers.  There is a correspondence between the rational numbers and the cuts that cut on the rational numbers and we can refer to such a cut as $\overline{1/2}$ as the cut that cuts on 1/2.

The other cuts that cut *between* rational numbers are extra cuts.

So... back to the collection of all possible cuts...

They form a number system.

For two cuts $\overline x$ and $\overline y$ we say $\overline x < \overline y$ if $A\overline x \subset A\overline y$.  We note that if we define $\alpha$ = $A\overline x + A\overline y = $ {all rationals that are sums of two rationals one in $A\overline x$ and the other in $A\overline y$} and $\beta$ = {all the rationals that are bigger than all the rationals in $\alpha$}, then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ perform a cut.

[*Again, I'm pulling a fast one.  Another brownie point to whoever finds it.  It's the same as the fast one I pulled above.*]

We define $\overline x + \overline y$ as finding that type of cut.

Similarly we define subtraction, multiplication, and division.  (Divisions kind of a pain to define but we do it.)

So the collection of all cuts form a number system.  What's more, the cuts that cut "on" rational numbers behave *equivalently* as the rational numbers do.

These "cuts" are the real numbers.  Every real number is a point at which we "cut" the rational numbers into two sets.  If we cut "on" a rational number that point is the rational number, if we cut "between" rational numbers that point is some irrational number.

That's it.  That's what the heck Real Numbers are.

... deep sigh and coffee break....

Okay, WHAT THE #@&! DOES THAT HAVE TO DO WITH .9999....?

Notice that we now have *discovered* (NOT "defined"; NOT "assumed") that every real number cuts the rationals in two.  So every bounded sequence of rationals can be fit into the $A\overline x$ set of some cut $\overline x$ and we can find precisely the lowest cut that will do that.  And that cut point is a precise and unique real number.

Thus the FUNDAMENTAL PROPERTY OF REAL NUMBERS!!!!  Every real number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers and every bounded sequence of rational numbers has a real number limit.  And this real number is the point that cuts the rational numbers at precisely the "edge" of the sequence.

So let's look at $.9999...... = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^n}$ and let's look at this bounded sequence of rational numbers: {.9; .99; .999; etc.} and let's look at the number $1$ which is larger than all the elements of the sequence.

So we know:

1)There is a cut $\overline {\omega}$ where $A\overline{\omega}$ = {all the rationals that are less than or equal to sum .999...9}

2)This cut occurs at a real number, $\omega$.

3)$\omega = \lim $ of the sequence {.9;.99;.999; etc.}

4).999.... "lingers" between the elements of $A\overline {\omega}$ and the elements of $B\overline{\omega}$.

Therefore we can conclude $.999.... = \omega$.

And that's it:

$.9999..... = \sum 9/10^n = \lim \{.9'.99;.999;...\}$ is a real number.

Now it's trivial to prove $.99999..... = 1$.

And there was not a single assumption or circular definition.

Comment: Well, to be subtle... analysis has *proven* that all bounded sequences of rationals get closer and closer to one and precisely one real number.  And analysis has shown an infinite sum of decimals is the limit of the sequence.  So we *know* that the sequence gets closer to *exactly* one number and we *know* that what the number is is .9999...  What remains is to show that this number happens to be 1.

Comment: To say ".9, .99, .9999 gets closer and closer to 1 so if we do it an infinite number of times we say that is 1" is a bit like saying "Well, we put a cat in a box and we don't know if the cat is alive or dead so we say the cat is both".  They miss the basic point  and mislead into thinking everything is an estimate.

Comment: Put much simpler: x = 0.999..., 10x = 9.999..., 9x = 9, x = 1.

Comment: The point is that if we allow that recurring decimal to meaningfully represent any real number (and of course if we define it as $\displaystyle\sum\frac{9}{10^n}$) then that real number has to be $1$ since it can't be strictly less than $1$ and can't be strictly greater than $1$. But then the fact that we are making the assumption that $0.999\ldots$ "meaningfully" represents some real number.

Comment: "With or without real numbers we do have to define $0.9999$ as $\displaystyle\sum \dfrac{9}{10^n}$"-why?

Comment: "Every real number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers and every bounded sequence of rational numbers has a real number limit."-how do you define "limit" here?

Comment: @mistermarko not really.  The OP isn't interested in a proof (which are all trivial anyway) but whether a proof is relevant as s/he was under the belief that .999... had been defined to be 1.  Your proof assumes that .999... is a meaningful well-defined value to begin with.  so this actually supports his/her idea that .999... was pre-defined to be 1 in the first place which I claim it was not.  So, no, your statement is *not* "put much simpler".  Your statement is a complete opposite argument.

Comment: "But then the fact that we are making the assumption that 0.999…0.999… "meaningfully" represents some real number."  !!!NO!!!! we are *NOT* making any such assumption at all!  We are doing analysis for entirely unrelated reasons and discover as a result that infinite decimals converge to numbers.

Comment: "With or without real numbers we do have to define 0.99990.9999 as ... .  Why".  Because if we defined it as a pink chocolate elephant the confectionary guild would think it didn't have market value.  Decimals are defined as sums of digits over powers of 10.  That's what digits are.  .73 has to be 7/10 + 3/100.  .8109 has to be 8/10 + 1/100 + 0/1000 + 9/10000.  The .9999..... if it is anything has to be .9/10 + 9/100 + ....  But we have *NO* idea whether that is going to be well behaved or meaningful at all.  *THAT* was *NEVER* assumed and had to be proven.

Comment: @user170039 The limit is the limit of the sequence of $n$-digit truncations, defined in the standard way for limits of sequences. Since this is a nondecreasing sequence, it turns out this limit is just the supremum of all possible finite decimal truncations.

There are a number of open source books that give a fairly elementary introduction to sequences and limits that often touch on decimal expansions. See http://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf for example.

Comment: "how do you define limit?"  A set of elements such that all the elements are less than or equal to some number is *bounded above* and that number is an *upper bound*.  It's possible, in a number system, to have an infinite set that is bounded above that doesn't have a distinct *smallest* upper bound.  For example in the Rationals {$r^2 < 2$} is bounded above by 1.5 (and other numbers) but there is no single smallest number that is greater or equal to all such r.  .... to be continued...

Comment: .. continued...  A system such that every set that is bounded above must have a least upper bound, such a system is said to have *the least upper bound property*.  The rationals do *not* have the least upper bound property.  The reals *do*.  So ... if you have a bounded set of Rational numbers they will *always* have a real number least upper bound.  I was informally and slightly incorrectly using that when I said "limit".  ... to be continued....

Comment: ... continued.... The set {.9;.99;.999; etc.} is a set of rationals that is bounded above by 1.  It's not hard to see that 1 is the least upper bound of the set.  It's also not hard to see that if .9999..... where to mean anything at all that it would also be the least upper bound of the set.  But that's not *technically* the proper meaning of "limit" as the limit isn't necessarily the largest part of the set but the "final destination" of the set.   Or more precisely.... to be continued.....

Comment: .... continued....  A sequence is a countable set of elements {$q_1, q_2,......$}.  If the terms get "closer and closer" to .... something then we say it converges and that something is the limit.  There is a more precise definition.  If there is an element $v$ such that for any number $e > 0$ no matter how small $e$ is, we can find a point where all the $q_i$ terms are such that $|q_i - v| < e$ for all $i$ after a certain point.  (In other words the $q_i$ get infintisimally close the $v$.  The we say.... to be continued....

Comment: ... continued... Then we say {$q_i$} converges and $\lim q_i = v$.  Now, infinitely approaching sequences in the Rational numbers do not have to converge. (The rational numbers do not have the least upper bound property so it has some "holes" where numbers can get infinitely close together but not "get anywhere").  The reals *do* have the least upper bound property so infinitely approaching sequences *do* converge.  (If real numbers get infinitely close together there *is* ALWAYS a real number point they are are approaching).  .. to be ...continued....

Comment: ... continued.... That is what real numbers are;  They are the points that cut the rationals in two so that all infinitely approaching sequences approach one of these real cut points.  So that's what a limit is. ... so let's talk infinite decimals:  Take $0.a_1a_2a_3.....$ The take the sequence S = {.a_1; .a_1a_1;...}.  *and* take the sequence T = {.a_1 + 1/10; .a_1a_2 + 1/100;.....}.  Now $0.a_1a_2...$ is larger then all terms of S and smaller than all terms of T.   Both sequences converge to a real number ... to be continued...

Comment: ... continued... both S and T converge to real numbers because their elements get infinitely closer together and the real numbers have the least upper bound property So there are real numbers $x_1 = \lim S \le 0.a_1a_2... \le \lim T = x_2$.  But it's easy to verify that $\lim S = \lim T$  so $x_1 = 0.a_1a_2a_3.... = x_2$.  So $0.a_1a_2a_3.... = \lim \{0.a_1; 0.a_1a_2; 0.a_1a_2a_3; etc.\}$.  Okay so 0.99999.... = $\lim${.9;.99;.999;...}.  which can easily be shown to be 1.  *Nothing* assumed.  No circular definitions.  ... to be concluded...

Comment: ... concluded....  It all hinges on determining that there is a number system that extends the Rationals that has the least upperbound property.  And be examining the Real numbers and Dedekind cuts on the rationals, we determine that there is and it is the Real Numbers.

Comment: Oh, notice that in referring to the term $0.a_1a_2a_3...$ we did not assume it had an well defined meaning or value but that it *is* a sum it must fall between ranges.

Comment: One important thing.  We *never* started talking about infinite decimals until *AFTER* analysts such as Dedekind had defined and proven the reals were such a system with the least upper bound so that all sequences of rationals that infinitely approach have real limits. It's only *AFTER* that, that is was determined that infinite decimals were meaningful and well-defined and !*useful*!  They were shown to be a method to *thoroughly* describe the reals.  Unfortunately, they became a magic mantra to elementary school teachers and befuddled students.

Comment: What historical information?

Comment: @fleablood do you have a tl;dr for this answer/discussion?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand the original question, the question has not been answered. Not that the other posts are wrong but they always touch another topic. Actually two questions were asked:

> Does it make sense to prove $0.999\ldots=1$?
>
> Can one give any "meaning" of the symbol $0.999\ldots$ other that defining it to be 1?

Regarding the first question: I'll understand it in the way "Why are we interested in this?"

Mathematicians are often interested if something is unique in this case the [decimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation#Non-uniqueness_of_decimal_representation). $0.999\ldots=1$ proves by example that the decimal representation is not unique.

Now let's consider the second question. Yes we could give it another meaning, bacause we can define anything we want. But if we define it in another way without changing other definitions we obtain a contradiction.

Could we change the definitions in a way that $0.999\ldots \neq 1$ and they still are reasonable in a way? I would say probably yes but I'm no expert in this matter. [The Wikipedia article about $0.999\ldots$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) states following:

> The equality of 0.999… and 1 is closely related to the absence of nonzero infinitesimals in the real number system, the most commonly used system in mathematical analysis. Some alternative number systems, such as the hyperreals, do contain nonzero infinitesimals. In most such number systems, the standard interpretation of the expression 0.999… makes it equal to 1, but in some of these number systems, the symbol "0.999…" admits other interpretations that contain infinitely many 9s while falling infinitesimally short of 1.

You might want to read the wikipedia article in more detail.

Answer (score -2):

My answer is not essentially different from some of the ones presented above, except for some notation. My apologies beforehand. Let $X = \{0, 1,2,3, \cdots , 9\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ ($\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \dots\}$) where $X$ is equipped with the product topology. $X$ is a compact (metrizable) space, the space of "decimals".  Define a ``canonical'' continuous surjective map $\varphi: X \rightarrow [0, 1]$ by $\{r_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\ \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ \ r_k/10^k$. The map $\varphi$ is not injective since for instance $\varphi$ ( 5,0,0,0, $\ldots$)=$\varphi$ ( 4,9,9,9, $\ldots$)